# Google Play Services error dialog potential memory leak?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm taking a look at this example
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#CheckServices

Here is the code in question:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
    private boolean servicesConnected() {
        ...
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            ...
            // Google Play services was not available for some reason.
            // resultCode holds the error code.
        } else {
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                resultCode,
                this,
                CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If we take a look at `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(..)` we are passing a reference to `this` which happens to be an `Activity`.

The question is:
**Would this cause a memory leak during a configuration change?**

I guess the answer depends on how/if `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(..)` keeps the reference to `Activity` internally.

Answer (score 1):

Yep on my app it used to leak

If you have the Google play services error dialog up and then rotate again it will leak

This is the solution I put in place to solve the leak but this assumes your Google play services check is in onResume

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
private Dialog googlePlayErrorDialog;

@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        int isAvaiable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            Log.d("TEST", "GPS IS OK");
        }
        else if(isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING || 
                isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED || 
                isAvaiable == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_DISABLED)
        {
            googlePlayErrorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvaiable, this, 10);
            googlePlayErrorDialog.show();

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if(googlePlayErrorDialog != null)
        {
            googlePlayErrorDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

So the deal here is that I set the getErrorDialog equal to one my own dialog variable and then in onPause do a simple null check (to avoid dreaded null pointer exception!) and call dismiss.

I got the idea from reading this if you want more information

http://publicstaticdroidmain.com/2012/01/avoiding-android-memory-leaks-part-1/

Comment: That solves the memory leak but it is a poor user experience. Changing what is on screen across a configuration change is a poor user experience.

Comment: It would be poor if the dialog was to not appear exactly like it was before the configuration change. This is where onResume comes in. In this example, its fine because the GPS dialog would appear again anyway. For other dialogs, its just a simple matter of setting a Boolean if the dialog was displayed and then displaying it again via on Resume and restoring variables via onSavedInstanceState that the user changes in the dialog. This is why I prefer having dialog code in this own private method makes things easier and organised